# How can I run my driver's makefile that is based on qt4 libraries?

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, raspberry-pi, driver

I am trying to make a label printer (Custom-TPTCM60IIL) work from a Raspberry Pi 4. The manufacturer provided a driver that I tried to set up (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NK2meMolBeYGSdkrjSUtoz1JJoz6EjKR/view?usp=sharing), but it wouldn't work out for me. When I try to run the makefile it throws out the following error:

*gcc -o cimkenyomtato cimkenyomtato.c -I ./Linux/cpt-setup/include -L ./Linux/cpt-setup/lib  -Wl,-rpath=./Linux/cpt-setup/lib -lCPTApi
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libQtXml.so.4, needed by ./Linux/cpt-setup/lib/libCPTApi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libQtGui.so.4, needed by ./Linux/cpt-setup/lib/libCPTApi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libQtCore.so.4, needed by ./Linux/cpt-setup/lib/libCPTApi.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpng12.so.0, needed by ./Linux/cpt-setup/lib/libzint.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)*

Assuming from the file names, the 4th version of the Qt should be installed, I couldn't find a way/guide to install this version, only the 5th and the 6th and those didn't work out. I am quite a beginner in this area, but I would be grateful for any help regarding this problem!

If I should post any further information about the issue, please tell me.

Thank you in advance!

Greg

Answer (score 0):

The latest Qt 4.8.7 binaries and source can be be found [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/). There are some tutorials floating around for setting up Qt on a Raspberry Pi, [this one](https://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide) is geared towards Qt 5 but you may be able to gleam some relevant info from it.

Depending on the OS you're running on your Pi you may be able to simply install via a package manager using something like:
`sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev`